Location allocation, Network Analyst tool, ERROR 030024
How do I solve this error:

Executing routing service Job Id: "j3dd43803e92e4bacbde5b114e310f5d7".
Submitted. Executing... The number of Facilities to locate exceeds the
valid Facilities count. ERROR 030024: Solve returned a failure.
 General function failure. Failed to execute (SolveLocationAllocation).
Failed. ERROR 030024: S


Your problem statement is too sparse, but I'd think you'd want to start with, "The number of Facilities to locate exceeds the valid Facilities count."

Please [edit] your question to include details about what you were trying to do, and how you were trying it.  What parameters did you use?  Give a bit of detail about the data you were using
